# How to invert the as? Statement and chain two as? operations

Tags: swift

I am currently trying to check if an object is not kind of two classes. In Objective-C I would do it like that:

```
if (![vc isKindOfClass:class1] && ![vc isKindOfClass:class2]) {
    // Do some work
}
```

In Swift I ended up with Code like this:

```
var isClass1 = false
var isClass2 = false

if let _  = self.window!.rootViewController as? Class1  {
    isClass1 = true
}

if let _  = self.window!.rootViewController as? Class2  {
    isClass2 = true
}

if (!isClass1 && !isClass2) {
    // Do some work
}
```

This looks like too much code for me. This is the result of swift noob trying to develop in swift. Is there a way to invert the as? and chain both statements somehow like I did in obj-C? It would be really nice to see a shorter and more advanced approach of solving this issue because this can't be the right solution :D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `is` operator:

```
if !(vc is Class1) && !(vc is Class2) {
    // do some work
}
```

Or, better (and more Swift-ish), you can use `guard` at the beginning of your method:

```
guard !(vc is Class1  || vc is Class2) else {
    return
}
// do some work
```

The `guard` condition is the same as the one from `if`, I only grouped it to have only one negation.

`guard` is the preferred method of validating inputs, as usually guards are placed at the beginning of the function, and the compiler forces you to return from the function on the `else` branch, this reduces the chance you forgot to return and the method body executes regardless the validity of the input data.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `is` keyword:

```
let vc = self.window!.rootViewController
if !(vc is Class1 || vc is Class2) {
    print("neither class1 nor class2")
}
```

Alternatively use the following if you want to do something in case `Class1` or `Class2`:

```
if let c1  = self.window!.rootViewController as? Class1  {
    // do something with c1
} else if let c2  = self.window!.rootViewController as? Class2  {
    // do something with c2
} else {
    // neither of type Class1 or Class2
}
```